# How to add an inline svg behind an iframe object?

Tags: html, svg, iframe, background-image, xlink

I currently facing an issue where I have a Iframe object, which I hide and show, and when hidden should an SVG be shown.

how to make sure that this SVG is behind the iframe.

I am currently have added it using inline `SVG` as I use `use` to grab it?

So my situation currently is

```
<div class="player">
<div style="width: 100px;height: 100px;display: block;margin: auto;">
<svg>
<use xlink:href=".."></use>
</svg>
</div>
<div style="height: 0px; padding-bottom: 56.25%; position: relative;">
<iframe width="400" height="245" src="//https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;" id="iframe1"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

The outer div `player` adds an background

The child div of `player` adds the style for the SVG

`svg` and `use` insert the SVG file, currenly above the `iframe`

and the `iframe` below the SVG image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal approach to overlaying two elements is to have a container element with `position: relative` and set `position: absolute` on the child elements.

Elements with absolute positioning can be positioned relative to the nearest ancestor that is positioned. That is why we are doing `position: relative` on the parent.

Eg.

```css
.player {
  position: relative;
}

.player > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="player">
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 100px;">
    <svg>
      <use xlink:href=".."></use>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div style="height: 0px; padding-bottom: 56.25%;">
    <iframe width="400" height="245" src="//https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;" id="iframe1"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, seem to work.. Any way it is possible to center the SVG in the player class?

Comment: @PaulLebau no way to center the SVG?

Comment: Yes of course. Just use one of the standard ways to centre an element.  Or you can set your SVG `viewBox` to appropriate values for your needs.